# RecyclerView understanding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to write an Android App which contains a Scrollable List aka RecyclerView, thanks to this tutorial:
https://www.avinsharma.com/android-basics-recyclerview-II/
I managed to make to entries clickable, but what I dont understand yet is following:

My Adapter:

```
class ExerciseAdapter(private val context: Context, private val dataset: List<Exercise>,
                  private val mOnClickListener: ExerciseAdapter.addRepClickListener)
                    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ItemViewHolder>(){
```

Onclick in Adapter:

```
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val position = adapterPosition
        mOnClickListener.addRep(position)
        Log.d(TAG, ""+position+"Clicked!")
    }
```

My Call from Mainactivity which works fine:

```
recyclerView.adapter = ExerciseAdapter(this, myDataset, this)
```

So naturally i tried this, inside Adapter:

```
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val position = adapterPosition
        context.addRep(position)
        Log.d(TAG, ""+position+"Clicked!")
    }
```

But it fails, I'm pretty new to this stuff why doesnt it work it's the same object in the end? Also I want to have multiple clickable areas per entry so I would end up with passing **this** 4-5 times and implementing 5 different interfaces?
There must be a better cleaner way.

Also how can I access the clicked View Siblings from Mainactivity? Sth like this:

```
    override fun addRep(position: Int) {
    textview_counter.text = textview_counter.text ++
}
```

Here is my adapter's code

```
class ExerciseAdapter(
    private val context: Context, 
    private val dataset:   List<Exercise>,
    private val mOnClickListener: ExerciseAdapter.addRepClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    interface addRepClickListener {
        fun addRep(position: Int)
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener{
        val tvVideo = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_video)
        val textActualreps = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_reps)
        val tvAddrep = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_plus)
        val textName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_name)
        val textLoad = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_load)

        init{
            tvAddrep.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            mOnClickListener.addRep(position)
            Log.d(TAG, ""+position+"Clicked!")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_ex, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val exercise = dataset[position]
        holder.textName.text = exercise.exerciseName
        holder.textLoad.text = exercise.load.toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount()  = dataset.size

    fun addRep(holder: ItemViewHolder){

    }
}
```

Help appreciated :-)

Comment: this will not work.  ` context.addRep(position)`

Comment: Yes but why? Its the same object which gets passed for context as for mOnClickListener

Comment: because you are passing reference of activity and receiver is a Context class in adapter's parameter. Make it same as the activity then it will work.

Comment: Can you post your full adapter code?

Comment: Added @luca_999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your adapter's code like this

```
class ExerciseAdapter(
    private val context: Context, 
    private val dataset:   List<Exercise>,
    private val mOnClickListener: ExerciseAdapter.addRepClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName

    inner class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvVideo = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_video)
        val textActualreps = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_reps)
        val tvAddrep = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_plus)
        val textName = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_name)
        val textLoad = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tevi_load)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_ex, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val exercise = dataset[position]
        holder.textName.text = exercise.exerciseName
        holder.textLoad.text = exercise.load.toString()
        holder.setOnClickListener {
            addRep(position)
            Log.d(TAG, ""+position+"Clicked!")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size

    private fun addRep(position: Int){
        // Exec your code for the on click event...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I dont have to pass this 5 times.